# Use Symfony as Web Services

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, ionic-framework

I am developing a mobile application in Ionic framework and uses Symfony framework as web services.when I post the data to symfony controller I got error:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/login. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
Here is my code

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .factory('Stack',function($http,$q,ApiEndpoint){

       var baseurl =ApiEndpoint.url;

      // alert(baseurl);
      // var baseurl =ApiEndpoint.url;
        return{

        Login:function(info){
        //  alert(info);
               var Url = baseurl+'/login';

               var defer = $q.defer();

              // console.log(item);
               $http.post(Url,info).

                  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                      defer.resolve(data);
                  }).
                  error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      defer.reject();
                  });

                return defer.promise;
       },

      }

    })
```

My Ionic Controller is:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('login', function($scope,$state,Stack) {


$scope.user = {};

console.log($scope.user.username);

     $scope.signIn = function(){

      var username = $scope.user.username;
      var password = $scope.user.password;



  var data = "pass=" +  username + "&mobiles=" + password;
       Stack.Login(data).then(function(response){

      //  $scope.data = response.totalLease;

        });  
  }


  $state.go('login');

})
```

My Symfony controller is:

```
 public function loginAction()
 {
     $response = new Response(json_encode(array('data' => 'a')));
     $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
 //   $response->headers->set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST");
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     return $response;
}
```

My Routing is:

```
sample_email:
    pattern:  /login/{_locale}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Demo:login, _format: json, _locale: en}
    requirements:
        _method:  GET|POST 
        _format: JSON
```

Comment: Do your Symfony and Angular apps are on the same domain ? (localhost)

Comment: Yes I am using localhost @Okazari

Comment: May be you use different ports for Symfony and for JS application?

Comment: Symfony Url: http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/login   and Ionic Url: http://localhost:8101/ionic-lab

Comment: Have you tried to run symfony built-in server on the same port than your Ionic app ? 

Like `app/console server:run 127.0.0.1:8101`

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this at the beginning of your symfony's web/.htaccess

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With,content-type,X-Forwarded-Proto
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS
```

It will allow all origins for your xhr calls. It's okay for a dev environment, but you better specify explicitly your origins in production.

Also browsers use method OPTIONS to check availability of a webservice.

More infos on OPTION method here : [RESTful API methods; HEAD & OPTIONS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660019/restful-api-methods-head-options)

Comment: When you're testing an api call in your browser, does it generate a request with the method OPTIONS ? (you can see all requests in Chrome's inspector network console for example)

Comment: When I post the data then the cross origin problem occurs. Otherwise all is good.

Comment: Just to be sure, try to add this code to your web/app.php (or app_dev.php)

`if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

    exit(0);
}`

You can also find more info about CORS here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Again same problem occurs after adding into app_Dev.php