# how to make an OPTIONS request with HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient

How do I send an OPTIONS request with System.Net.Http.HttpClient

exposed methods for HttpClient

- DeleteAsync
- GetAsync
- PostAsync
- PutAsync
- few others as well.....

I was expecting a OptionsAsync

```
   switch (httpMethod) {
      case HTTP_METHODS.DELETE:
       {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.DeleteAsync(uri).Result;
        break;
       }
      case HTTP_METHODS.GET:
       {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
        break;
       }
      case HTTP_METHODS.POST:
       {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PostAsync(uri, httpContent).Result;
        break;
       }
      case HTTP_METHODS.PUT:
       {
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PutAsync(uri, httpContent).Result;
        break;
       }
      case HTTP_METHODS.OPTION:
       {
        //not sure what method to call on httpclient here to make Options request
        httpResponseMessage = httpClient.PutAsync(uri, httpContent).Result;
        if (httpResponseMessage.Headers.Contains("X-CSRF-TOKEN")) {
         IEnumerable < string > headerValues = httpResponseMessage.Headers.GetValues("X-CSRF-TOKEN");
         csrfToken = headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        break;
       } 
     }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660019/restful-api-methods-head-options

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no wrappers for that kind of methods (e.g. `OPTIONS` and `HEAD`), but you could use `SendAsync` just like these wrappers do:

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Options, "url");
var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the expected response back, you have to make sure to set the "Origin" header in the request, like so:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Options, "url");
message.Headers.Add("Origin", "http://example.com");
var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
```